# JBOSS Server has Errors when calling a page

Tags: java, servlets, jboss, db2

I have got the following error

```
  java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver from [Module  deployment.Shopping.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
```

How can I find a solution for that ?

Comment: Have you deployed the JDBC driver?

Comment: Do you have a .jar file called 'db2jcc-9.jar' (or similar) somewhere?

Comment: Yes I have JDBC jar files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably you did not deploy the required DB2 JDBC driver correctly.

The simplest way to do this is to copy the drivers .jar file (should be called `db2jcc-9.jar` or similar) into the `lib` directory of your server configuration.

(For the *default* configuration, the `/lib` directory is `*[JBOSS-HOME]/server/default/lib*)`.